# How to associate CSV file to my app, both in email attachment and device storage?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

My app has a feature to import CSV files and can be opened by choosing a CSV file.

1/ When I open the app by clicking the CSV file attached in email, it works successfully.

2/ I downloaded the same CSV file as above into Download folder of the device, then tried opening the app via this file. In this case, the app does not appear in the Open With list.

My goal is to make the app appear in the Open With list for both cases above.

```xml
        <activity
            android:name=".IntroScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/ZPTAppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/csv"/>
                <data android:host="*" />

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this code from somewhere it might be helpful

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-flac"/>
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

this is for audio type but you can use it for another perpous.